# finding the coordinate that lies in the vector and through it

Tags: calculus, vectors

I'm trying to find the coordinates of A, where the line $l_1$ is given by this equation:

$$\begin{pmatrix}8 \\ 1 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix} +\mathbf{\mu} \begin{pmatrix}-5 \\ 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} $$

Where $\mu$ is a scalar parameter = 1. The point A lies on the equation provided above.

Find the coordinates of A.

My approach:
Given $\mu$ = 1; Then is A = $8  -5\mu=3?$

Furthermore, The point P has position vector:

$$\begin{pmatrix}  1  \\ 5 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} $$

The line $l_2$ passes through the point P and is parallel to the line $l_1$, whats the vector equation for line $l_2$?

Do I have to do this?

$$\begin{pmatrix}8 \\ 1 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix} +\mathbf{\mu} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Given that $\mu$ = 1; then

$$\begin{pmatrix}  10 \\ 11 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \implies \begin{pmatrix}10 \\ 11 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} +\mathbf{\mu} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Then If I'm to find the exact distance AP, giving an answer in the form $k\sqrt{2}$, where is to be determined how to I proceed?

And if the acute angle between AP and $l_2$ is $\theta$, how to find $\cos\theta?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\mu=1$ the point is
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}8 \\ 1 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix} +1\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-5 \\ 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
The line $l_2\parallel l_1$ is simply
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} +\mathbf{\lambda} \begin{pmatrix}-5 \\ 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} $$
$AP=\sqrt{(3-1)^2+(5-5)^2+(0-2)^2}=2\sqrt{2}$

$\vec{AP}=(3,5,0)-(1,5,2)=(2,0,-2)$ and $|\vec{AP}|=\sqrt{2^2+0^2+(-2)^2}=2\sqrt{2}$

The direction vector of $l_2$ is $\vec{u}=(-5,4,3)$, and $|\vec{u}|=\sqrt{(-5)^2+4^2+3^2}=5\sqrt 2$

The cosine of the angle between $AP$ and $l_2$ is
$$\cos\theta=\frac{\vec{AP}\cdot \vec{u}}{|\vec{AP}||\vec{u}|}=\frac{2\cdot 3+0\cdot 5+(-2)\cdot 0}{(2\sqrt 2)(5\sqrt 2)}=\frac{3}{10}$$

**edit**

Given $AP=PE$ and $E$ is on line $l_2$ means that we intersect the line $l_2$ with the sphere with center $(1,5,2)$ and radius $2\sqrt 2$, whose equation is $$(x-1)^2+(y-5)^2+(z-2)^2=8$$
while parametric equation of line $l_2$ is
$$l_2:(1-5\lambda,5+4\lambda,2+3\lambda)$$
substitute these last ones into the equation od the sphere and get
$$(3 \lambda +2-2)^2+(4 \lambda +5-5)^2+(-5 \lambda +1-1)^2=8$$
which gives
$$50 \lambda ^2=8\to \lambda=\pm\frac{2}{5}$$
if $\lambda=\frac{2}{5}$ then point $E$ has coordinates $E_1=\left(-1,\frac{33}{5},\frac{16}{5}\right)$

if $\lambda=-\frac{2}{5}$ then point $E$ has coordinates $E_2=\left(3,\frac{17}{5},\frac{4}{5}\right)$

The triangle is isosceles, so the area is $\frac12\cdot AE_2\cdot PM$ where $M$ is the midpoint of $AE_2$. Coordinates of $M$ are the mean (average) of the coordinates of $A$ and $E_2$.

$M=(3,4.2,0.4)$ and $$PM=\sqrt{\left(1-3\right)^2+\left(5-4.2\right)^2+\left(2-0.4\right)^2}=\frac{6}{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$AE_2=PE_2=\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$Area_{APE_2}=Area_{APE_1}=\frac12\cdot\frac{6}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot \frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}=2.4$$

Comment: If a point E lies on the line $l_2$, given that AP = PE; How do I find the area of triangle APE, along with coordinates of two possible positions of E?

Comment: I added the area. The two area are equal. @Workaroundcode

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're struggling a bit with the concept of a line expressed through vectors. I think understanding the equation for the line will help answer your questions.

Take a line in two dimensions, say $ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \mu *\begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then this tells you that starting from the point $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, all points in the space that can be reached through the vector $\mu *\begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ are a part of the line.

The rule for vector addition is very simple, you just add the coordinates. I.e. the points on this line are $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + 1 *\begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 0+\mu *(-1) \\ 0 +\mu *1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -\mu \\ \mu \end{pmatrix}$ for all values of $\mu$.

For instance, let point A be that point on the line where $\mu =1$. Then $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + 1 *\begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$

Now, the same holds for your problem. Your A is a point in a three-dimensional space, and what you've done is calculate just the first coordinate of A. You want to do the same for the other two coordinates as well, so $A=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}$.

If you understand how the line works, then you also know how to create a line that is parallel to l1 and goes through a different point. What makes the line parallel is the direction vector, which is $\begin{pmatrix} -5\\ 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ in your case. So, the simplest solution for l2 is $P+\mu *\begin{pmatrix} -5\\ 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$.

Last part of this answer: Think about how you calculate a "distance" in one dimension. Say, the distance between the numbers 3 and 1. That's 3-1=2. Same goes in your vector space: the distance between $\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} y_1\\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix}$ is the length of the vector $\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} y_1\\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 - y_1\\ x_2 - y_2 \\ x_3 - y_3 \end{pmatrix} $. You can look up easily how to calculate the length of a vector.

Hope this helps!